# Can't seem to get text entered in a Jtextfield and use that text to replace JLabels when "Submit" button is pressed

Tags: java

First off sorry for the crappy formatting I'm fairly new to Java. But onto the problem. I am trying to make a jeopardy game in java and I've just started. I can't figure out how to retrieve the information from a JTextfield, where it asks the users to enter their names (After "Start" button is pressed), and use that Text to replace the JLabels "Player 1:" & "Player 2:" when they press the "Submit" Button. The answer seems fairly simple and yet I can't figure out and its extremely frustrating. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; 

class JeopardyCulminating implements ActionListener
{
  JLabel mConversion, ints, fAndR, variableExp, algebra;
  JLabel playerScore, one, two;
  JLabel jeopardyTitle;
  JTextField player1, player2;
  JButton h11, h21, h31, h41, h51;
  JButton h12, h22, h32, h42, h52;
  JButton h13, h23, h33, h43, h53;
  JButton h14, h24, h34, h44, h54;
  JButton h15, h25, h35, h45, h55;
  JButton startButton;
  JFrame frame;
  String zero = "0", zero1 = "0";
  int playerCount = 2;
  int scoreCounter = 0;

  int score[][] = new int[playerCount][scoreCounter];
  String jokes[][] = new String[100][100];

  JeopardyCulminating()
  {
    // Setting the frame layout and setting the exit button
    frame = new JFrame("GUI Jeopardy"); 
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
    frame.setSize(390,750); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

// Title label
jeopardyTitle = new JLabel("Welcome to The Game of Jeopardy! 8th-9th Grade Math Edition!");
jeopardyTitle.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));

// Creating the category labels
mConversion = new JLabel("<html>Measurement<br>Conversion</html>");
ints = new JLabel("Integers");
fAndR = new JLabel("<html>Fractions<br>& Rationals</html>");
variableExp = new JLabel("<html>Variable<br>Expressions</html>");
algebra = new JLabel("Algebra");

// JTextField keeping track of score
player1 = new JTextField(7);
player2 = new JTextField(7);
player1.addActionListener(this);
player1.setEditable(false);
player1.setText(zero); 
player2.addActionListener(this);
player2.setEditable(false);
player2.setText(zero1);

// Score Labels
playerScore = new JLabel("Score:");
one = new JLabel("Player 1:");
two = new JLabel("Player 2:");

// Start Menu
startButton = new JButton("Start");
startButton.addActionListener(this);

// First column buttons
h11 = new JButton("$100a");
h11.addActionListener(this);
h11.setEnabled(false);
h21 = new JButton("$200a");
h21.addActionListener(this);
h21.setEnabled(false);
h31 = new JButton("$300a");
h31.addActionListener(this);
h31.setEnabled(false);
h41 = new JButton("$400a");
h41.addActionListener(this);
h41.setEnabled(false);
h51 = new JButton("$500a");
h51.addActionListener(this);
h51.setEnabled(false);

// Second column buttons
h12 = new JButton("$100b");
h12.addActionListener(this);
h12.setEnabled(false);
h22 = new JButton("$200b");
h22.addActionListener(this);
h22.setEnabled(false);
h32 = new JButton("$300b");
h32.addActionListener(this);
h32.setEnabled(false);
h42 = new JButton("$400b");
h42.addActionListener(this);
h42.setEnabled(false);
h52 = new JButton("$500b");
h52.addActionListener(this);
h52.setEnabled(false);

// Third column buttons
h13 = new JButton("$100c");
h13.addActionListener(this);
h13.setEnabled(false);
h23 = new JButton("$200c");
h23.addActionListener(this);
h23.setEnabled(false);
h33 = new JButton("$300c");
h33.addActionListener(this);
h33.setEnabled(false);
h43 = new JButton("$400c");
h43.addActionListener(this);
h43.setEnabled(false);
h53 = new JButton("$500c");
h53.addActionListener(this);
h53.setEnabled(false);

// Fourth column buttons
h14 = new JButton("$100d");
h14.addActionListener(this);
h14.setEnabled(false);
h24 = new JButton("$200d");
h24.addActionListener(this);
h24.setEnabled(false);
h34 = new JButton("$300d");
h34.addActionListener(this);
h34.setEnabled(false);
h44= new JButton("$400d");
h44.addActionListener(this);
h44.setEnabled(false);
h54 = new JButton("$500d");
h54.addActionListener(this);
h54.setEnabled(false);

// Fifth column buttons
h15 = new JButton("$100e");
h15.addActionListener(this);
h15.setEnabled(false);
h25 = new JButton("$200e");
h25.addActionListener(this);
h25.setEnabled(false);
h35 = new JButton("$300e");
h35.addActionListener(this);
h35.setEnabled(false);
h45 = new JButton("$400e");
h45.addActionListener(this);
h45.setEnabled(false);
h55 = new JButton("$500e");
h55.addActionListener(this);
h55.setEnabled(false);

frame.add(jeopardyTitle);
frame.add(mConversion);
frame.add(ints);
frame.add(fAndR);
frame.add(variableExp);
frame.add(algebra);
frame.add(h11);
frame.add(h12);
frame.add(h13);
frame.add(h14);
frame.add(h15);
frame.add(h21);
frame.add(h22);
frame.add(h23);
frame.add(h24);
frame.add(h25);
frame.add(h31);
frame.add(h32);
frame.add(h33);
frame.add(h34);      
frame.add(h35);      
frame.add(h41);        
frame.add(h42);         
frame.add(h43);          
frame.add(h44);         
frame.add(h45);         
frame.add(h51);          
frame.add(h52);          
frame.add(h53);
frame.add(h54);          
frame.add(h55);
frame.add(playerScore);
frame.add(one);
frame.add(player1);
frame.add(two);
frame.add(player2);
frame.add(startButton);
frame.setVisible(true);
}

// the problem is here:
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
{ 
  if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Start")) 
  {   
    startButton.setVisible(false);

    JLabel rules = new JLabel("Rules & How to Play:");
    JLabel rules1 = new JLabel("*rules here*");

    JLabel names = new JLabel("Enter player names: ");
    JLabel player1 = new JLabel("Enter player 1's name:");
    JLabel player2 = new JLabel("Enter player 2's name:");

    JTextField playerName1 = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField playerName2 = new JTextField(15);
    playerName1.addActionListener(this);
    playerName2.addActionListener(this);

    JButton submitName = new JButton("Submit");
    submitName.addActionListener(this);

    frame.add(rules);
    frame.add(rules1);
    frame.add(names);
    frame.add(player1);
    frame.add(playerName1);
    frame.add(player2);
    frame.add(playerName2);
    frame.add(submitName);
  }

    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Submit"))
    {
      h11.setEnabled(true);
      h21.setEnabled(true);
      h31.setEnabled(true);
      h41.setEnabled(true);
      h51.setEnabled(true);
      h12.setEnabled(true);
      h22.setEnabled(true);
      h32.setEnabled(true);
      h42.setEnabled(true);
      h52.setEnabled(true);
      h13.setEnabled(true);
      h23.setEnabled(true);
      h33.setEnabled(true);
      h43.setEnabled(true);
      h53.setEnabled(true);
      h14.setEnabled(true);
      h24.setEnabled(true);
      h34.setEnabled(true);
      h44.setEnabled(true);
      h54.setEnabled(true);
      h15.setEnabled(true);
      h25.setEnabled(true);
      h35.setEnabled(true);
      h45.setEnabled(true);
      h55.setEnabled(true);

      jokes[0][0] = playerName1.getText();
      jokes[0][1] = playerName2.getText();
      one.setText(playerName1.getText());
      two.setText(playerName2.getText());
    }
}     

public static void main(String args[])     
{     
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){ 
    public void run(){ 
      new JeopardyCulminating();     
    } 
  });     
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
    submitName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Execute when button is pressed
                  one.setText(playerName1.getText());
                  two.setText(playerName2.getText());
        }
    });
```

will be much easier and clearer of what is happening when submitName button is pressed.

Also, its good practice to put all your column and row buttons in a list and then just iterate over if you want to create operations on them such as adding to a frame or enabling them, it looks better and its easier to read.

Goodluck

Comment: Thanks! I'll attempt to implement this into my code when I get a chance today, I am new to java so I might have some trouble but I'll figure out. Thanks again!